# Can I remove the valve cover to retrieve the extension with 8mm socket that fell into my engine?

Tags: ford, valve, expedition

I dropped an extension with a 8 mm socket attached into the plug hole. I started the engine for like five to 10 seconds to see if it blew out. I read that starting the engine was an huge mistake. With all that said, can I retrieve the extension by taking off the valve cover? If so, how and what's the easy way to take off the valve cover step by step? I already have the tire off and eye balling the lower bolts but I don't know about the top bolts and how many bolts total are on a 2002 Ford Expedition valve cover?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get into the combustion chamber so the head needs to come off - the valve cover is one of the preliminary steps...

Edit due to your duplicate post... I suggested a magnetic tool and you say they are all too large, well I have just taken a picture of mine and as you can see it is similar in diameter to the pen and pencil shown with it - it is also telescopic to about 20"...
[image]

Comment: @DanielThompson If this is a V8 Triton motor you need to have someone experienced in doing 2v/3v timing sets when you pull the head or you're going to bend valves.

Comment: Thanks, sound like I'm stuck between a rock and hard place. I have hand held tools and several ratchets sets. Tell me that is all I need to do the job. Sounds like I have to remove almost everything out of the engine just to get to the combustion chambers from the hours of video I've watched. Please help me step by step please. I'm desperately need my vehicle up and running again.

Comment: Can't afford nobody experience so I'm studying to critically think and resolve the problem with internet help. How long did it take you how to do the timing so valves wouldn't be damage? I need you man! Teach me or I'm stuck. Hate to admit this but my 2002 ford expedition 5.4 liter motor is almost the only friend I have and trust. Now the SUV has turned his back on me and ate my tools. My SUV has attempted suicide but we can't allow him to die. I read I need all kind of special tools to do the head removal procedure. What do you think? I should give up and sell him as is?

Comment: @DanielThompson There are way to many steps in the procedure and tools needed for a comment. It's best to post a new question. Also If you've never done this before, I'd be very cautious about doing this yourself. If you didn't already bend a valve with the extension still in the cylinder, you need to do a leak down test to see if this is even worth doing. It's very easy to mess up cam timing on these as there aren't any marks on the crank or cams. And you need to rely on special tools or have a way to scribe marks on the cam and crank gears to keep everything aligned

Comment: Thanks, I know it take years of experience or schooling and specialty tools to do the job. I just hate to admit defeat. Hopefully I will be able to work out some type of payment plan with a wanna be mechanic who has professional friends who he can borrow the tools from to do the job. I know a couple of people and hopefully they will do it for only a couple of hundred dollars. How much does a job like this cost by an professional?

Comment: @DanielThompson I'll also point out that the cheapest I've seen the cam holding tools is about $80-130 a piece and the crank holding tool is around $50. Depending on which head has to be removed you're looking at 18-20 book hours.

Comment: Well, buying the tools and having them for personal training is an good experience for me right? I can only make things worst. I turned the engine for 5 to10 seconds and now I'm told I could have locked my engine. In any case it's damaged. I know I didn't lock the engine but I'm afraid to turn the key to find out. I have to have some one fix it like you said.

Comment: @DanielThompson Well take a look at this PDF it should contain everything to R&I the engine and R&R the cylinder heads. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b7nsxscrjws8h9/alotofwork.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried a magnet tool to extract the items ? Id also look at an inspection camera to see what you have before tearing the head off.....

Comment: @r.anderson This is the third question about the same problem by the OP, most options have been proposed... magnetic tools etc And, he did buy one but didn't check the size so it would not fit through the plug hole .... Go figure...